# How can I add various options to my script

Tags: python

I am very new to Python. In the following script, how can I add more options to the files that I want to obtain. Like, let's say that I am not sure how the file is called. My options for the name of that file are: "Unicorn 1.pdf", "Unicorn 2.pdf, and "Apple 1.pdf".

```
import os
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

def fsf():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
        for file in files:
            **if file.endswith("Unicorn 1.pdf"):**
                pis = os.path.join(root, file)
                if pis == os.path.join(root, file):
                    pass
```

I think that I need to add an else after the **if file.endswith("Unicorn 1.pdf"):** , right?

Please help me as I don't know what to do.

Note that I am not sure how the file is called, and I want to have more options for the name of the file in case the first one is incorrect.

Comment: Please don't make us guess at how these "options" should present themselves to the user -- decide on exactly the behavior you're trying to achieve, in terms of whether you want to add a command-line argument, vs a prompt, vs whatever else, and look for existing duplicates describing how to do that thing and describe how you tried to apply their answers and what went wrong in doing so (or how/why they weren't helpful, otherwise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file.endswith("Unicorn 1.pdf")` means that you look for file whose name end with "Unicorn 1.pdf"
So you can do the same with only extention :

`file.endswith(".pdf")`

you can also use [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) if you prefer

Answer (score 2):

Use argparse:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--path', default='Unicorn 1.pdf')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.path)
# "Unicorn 1.pdf" or whatever you give to your program as input
```

Run from your terminal:

```
python your_program.py --path file.pdf
```

Note that if your filename contains spaces, you must use quotes `" "`.

```
python your_program.py --path "Unicorn 1.pdf"
```

Then, check if your default filename exists or not, an proceed accordingly.

```
import os
if os.path.exists(args.path):
    # do something with the file
else:
    # do something else, e.g. open another PDF with os.
    files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.pdf'):
             # do something, either with ALL or just ONE (using break) of the pdfs
```

Comment: Please don't add more answers to duplicates -- if this is clearly what the OP wants, this could just be closed as one of the many "how do I take command-line options in Python?" questions already answered describing how to use argparse. (I don't think what the OP wants is actually so clear as to be sure they mean a command-line option, so I would be closing the question as unclear or too-broad instead of duplicate, myself).

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, particularly the first and third bullet points therein.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well, sorry if the question was unclear and has already been answered many times. I am new to the language and to this platform and I just want to know how to proceed with my script.